# MySQL event update every friday at specific time

Tags: mysql, events, sql-update, mysql-event

So i want to `update` my `column point` and make it `0 every friday at 15:00` this is my code:

```
CREATE EVENT updatepoints
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 WEEK
STARTS CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 4 - WEEKDAY(CURRENT_DATE) DAY, '15:00:00'
DO
UPDATE people SET point = 0;
```

I get the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ' '15:00:00' DO UPDATE people SET point = 0' at line 4

Comment: The error is quite clear, you have an extraneous `, '15:00:00'` there for some reason. You'll have to add it to the timestamp and a comma isn't going to do that.

Comment: Yes i know that but im not sure how, thats why im asking the question.